# SQLAlchemy ORM Insertion based on related object

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

This is kind of a newbie question. I am new to ORM and I would like to know if the following is possible:

Let's say I have a "users" table with three fields: "id", "user_name", and a foreign key "country_id" that points to the table "countries"

[image: Tables Relation]

Now, if I want to insert a new user, I first look for the id of the country in "countries" table (for instance 11) and then I create an instance of User (declarative base object)

```
new_user = User('Johnny', 11)
session.add(new_user)
```

What I would like to know, if it is possible to add directly the new user, passing only the country name... something like this:

```
new_user = User('Johnny', Country('Spain')) # Note the country instance
session.add(new_user)
```

I tried things like this, but the best result I got is that the ORM tries to insert another country called Spain.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What tool did you use to generate that diagram?

Comment: Hi, I used wwwsqldesigner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `Spain` **has already been inserted** in the database, you'll need the following:

```
new_user = User(name='Johnny', country_id=session.query(Country).filter_by(name='Spain').one().id)
```

which in a clearer version is:

```
country = session.query(Country).filter_by(name='Spain').one()
new_user = User(name='Johnny', country_id=country.id)
```

if you have a `User.country` [`relationship`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html) defined this can simply be:

```
country = session.query(Country).filter_by(name='Spain').one()
new_user = User(name='Johnny', country=country)
```

if the `User.country` relationship has a `users` [`backref`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#linking-relationships-with-backref) relationship defined (which will be mapped by default to a `list`), you can also do:

```
country = session.query(Country).filter_by(name='Spain').one()
country.users.add(User(name='Johnny'))
```

Comment: This is what I was doing. But still had the feeling it was a little bit "too manual", and maybe there could be a cleaner way to get it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I try to do `country = session.query(Country).filter_by(name='Spain')
new_user = User(name='Johnny', country=country)`, I receive a "'Query' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'".  It only works if I do country.first(), but that creates two SQL queries (select, insert).

Comment: Thanks for pointing the lack of `.one()` or `.first()` method calls to actually retrieve the instances @Pakman. Regarding the other point you make, either you already know country ID in advance and use that to insert the user without querying the database first, or if you only know the name, I don't see any way around first querying the database for the country ID by its name.